# Underfull \hbox error

Tags: tables

Could someone help me get rid of the following warning? I am getting the following: 
[image: snapshot of the table code and the error]

Comment: Try to use a higher value for the lengths.

Comment: Welcome! First, please always provide code - not a picture of it. Second, make it a minimal example - a complete document which we can reproduce the issue with. Third, is that code from the file mentioned in the message? If so, what @Sigur said. Otherwise, it isn't the code responsible for the message.

Comment: wow, I am impressed on your immediate answering, thanks so very much. well, thanks for the welcoming, yes I am new to all this. I thought I was showing the code that corresponds to the warning. I already used a higher value for the lengths and same problem.

Comment: The problem is that typesetting justified text on a 2cm line width is inherently difficult. You may want to use `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2cm}`, instead of `m{2cm}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big problem is typesetting justified text in columns so narrow, which is simply impossible.

Use ragged right typesetting, which can be obtained with

```
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2cm}
```

instead of `m{2cm}`. However, think again if you really want such narrow columns to begin with.

Here's an example: top with justified text (and lots of underfull boxes), bottom with ragged right text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-notilde]{babel}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | *{4}{m{2cm} |} }
\hline
Objectivo & Nivel Analítico & Técnica & Fuentes \\
\hline
Objectivo específico 1 &
Recolección de datos: primeros datos producto
de la revisión documental. &
Revisión documental &
Informes técnicos, memorias, OCDE (CPTC), COMEX, MICITT y otros.\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ | *{4}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2cm} |} }
\hline
Objectivo & Nivel Analítico & Técnica & Fuentes \\
\hline
Objectivo específico 1 &
Recolección de datos: primeros datos producto
de la revisión documental. &
Revisión documental &
Informes técnicos, memorias, OCDE (CPTC), COMEX, MICITT y otros.\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wouldn't use `m` columns, but `p` ones.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH FOR SUCH A DETAILED REPLY. I am very impressed on your immediate response, I only saw this now, my Mom was not feeling well today. I am going to try your indications. Thanks so very much.

Comment: By the way, your help in this  forum is so valuable. I learned to use tabular in the examples directly from LaTex help, however I am  finding out that several examples are not correct anymore, maybe they were, but not at the present time. Actually, I had used the columns width and table exactly in the same way about three months ago and I had not gotten any warnings nor errors, until now... So this tells me, something in the compiling process was changed by LaTex... what do you think?